# IIS - w3wp.exe crashes on loading the web service

Tags: iis, w3wp

I have a simple web service which loads and OCX. On calling a method of this OCX, which essentially makes a connection with remote server causing w3wp.exe to crash. I have no clue why this happens. In my assumption this could be a security issue because when I run the same from Visual Studio directly with logged in user doesn't have any problems. How to solve this? The following log has been captured from DebugDiag

**Type of Analysis Performed   Crash Analysis** 
Machine Name   INGBTCPIC5DT00L 
Operating System   Windows Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 
Number Of Processors   8 
Process ID   2088 
Process Image   C:\Windows\SysWOW64\inetsrv\w3wp.exe 
System Up-Time   02:06:52 
Process Up-Time   00:00:07

**Thread 32 - System ID 1320**
Entry point   ole32!CRpcThreadCache::RpcWorkerThreadEntry 
Create time   2/7/2012 5:09:58 PM 
Time spent in user mode   0 Days 0:0:0.46 
Time spent in kernel mode   0 Days 0:0:0.218

**Full Call Stack**

Function     Arg 1     Arg 2     Arg 3     Arg 4   Source 
ntdll!__ascii_strnicmp+1c     00000038     767c7bb0     0000000b     1d7b2aa0
gdi32!bCreateDCA+31     00000038     00000038     00000000     00000000
gdi32!CreateDCA+18     00000038     00000038     00000000     00000000
Common!MonProp::SetMonitorSizes+49     00000000     00000000     00000000     00000000

**Exception Information**
NTDLL!__ASCII_STRNICMP+1CIn w3wp_*DefaultAppPool*_PID_*2088*_Date__02_07_2012__Time_05_09_59PM_*625*_Second_Chance_Exception_C0000005.dmp the assembly instruction at ntdll!__ascii_strnicmp+1c in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll from Microsoft Corporation has caused an access violation exception (0xC0000005) when trying to read from memory location 0x00000038 on thread 32

**Module Information** 
Image Name: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll   Symbol Type:  PDB 
Base address: 0x00905a4d   Time Stamp:  Thu Nov 17 10:58:47 2011
Checksum: 0x00000000   Comments:
COM DLL: False   Company Name:  Microsoft Corporation 
ISAPIExtension: False   File Description:  NT Layer DLL 
ISAPIFilter: False   File Version:  6.1.7601.17725 (win7sp1_gdr.111116-1503) 
Managed DLL: False   Internal Name:  ntdll.dll 
VB DLL: False   Legal Copyright:  © Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved. 
Loaded Image Name:  ntdll.dll   Legal Trademarks:
Mapped Image Name:     Original filename:  ntdll.dll 
Module name:  ntdll   Private Build:
Single Threaded:  False   Product Name:  Microsoft® Windows® Operating System 
Module Size:  1.50 MBytes   Product Version:  6.1.7601.17725 
Symbol File Name:  c:\symcache\wntdll.pdb\D74F79EB1F8D4A45ABCD2F476CCABACC2\wntdll.pdb   Special